# Chrome acting weird, ignoring z-index

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am experiencing a weird issue with the z-index property, but only in Chrome. Chrome apparently deals with z-index in a different way than other browsers (child elements cannot overrule the parent's z-index etc), but I can't see why this would be the problem here, since this is about two parent-elements.

```
<div id="s-drop-mobil" style="z-index: 6000">
    <div id="s-drop">
    <p> Based in Stockholm,<br>Sweden</p>
        <a href="mailto:ok@w-i.zone">hi@robinradenman.se</a>
        <p style ="font-size: 0.8em"> +46 70-219 39 65</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="kat-wrap" style="z-index: 1">
    <div id="katalog">

    <a class="works-head" href="javascript:void(0);">S &nbsp;&nbsp;e &nbsp;&nbsp;l &nbsp;&nbsp;e &nbsp;&nbsp;c &nbsp;&nbsp;t &nbsp;&nbsp;e &nbsp;&nbsp;d&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; w &nbsp;&nbsp;o &nbsp;&nbsp;r &nbsp;&nbsp;k &nbsp;&nbsp;s</a><br>
    <a class="bruce-text" href="brucelabruce.html">BRUCE LABRUCE X DAMIEN BLOTTIERE X PAOM</a><br>
    <a class="greta-text" href="gretagram.html">GRETA GRAM S/S17 @ STOCKHOLM FASHION WEEK</a><br>
    <a class="colette-text" href="henzelcolette.html">HENZEL STUDIO COLLABORATIONS @ COLETTE, PARIS</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the #kat-wrap is always higher stacked than the #s-drop-mobil in Chrome. If I change the #kat-wrap z-index to -1 or lower, #s-drop-mobil will be stacked higher, but #kat-wrap will do a weird flickering when trying to show an img (with an even lower z-index, also parent) on hover with basic jQuery. Also, none of the relevant elements have a fixed position.

I'm not sure what else to show, but [this is the site](http://robinradenman.se), if anyone would like to take a look at it.

Any advice?

Comment: Add position:relative to the elements. Z-index works on positioned elements. Without that, the elements are stacked based on their layout.

Comment: The #kat-wrap needs to have a position:absolute for the layout to work though. I mean, since this is a problem regarding overlapping elements, both can't be position:relative anyways, or is there a way for position:relative elements to overlap?

Comment: Looking at your site, you're setting a z-index of 6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for `#s-drop-mobil`, which is well above the maximum constraints for z-index. You're also not setting a z-index for `#kat-wrap` at all on the live site. This may be causing some of the problem. However, looking at the live site myself in Chrome, it appears to work fine -- no noticeable flickering or issues with the z-index. You also have positions relative. Have you already fixed the problem?

Comment: Wow, 6 quindecillion. I had to look up that name.